# Where is a good source of documentation for Pylons web framework?

Tags: python, pylons

The documentation at http://pylonshq.com/docs/ seems quite out of date (as of January 2nd, 2011) and does not seem to be updated with any frequency. Are there other good resources for where to find information about best practices with Pylons, examples with Pylons, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just starting to use Pylons? In that case you might want to switch to Pyramid, which is "Pylons 2", so to speak. It's very well documented. (Although the site is currently down.) http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/ But if you are not, then this doesn't exactly help, so sorry about this almost answer.

Edit: The main site is now updated with Pyramid documentation:

http://docs.pylonshq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pyramid Documentation : http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/.

In this website, you'll understand why I give you the "Pyramid Documentation".

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question two months ago. I found the official documentation a bit tough on me(I m a python noob)searched again and found this [gem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599349). But Pyramid would be a better choice to learn right now as pylons is not actively developed.

I started with pylons and then pyramid and found both intimidatingly complex. So moved to [Django](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Adjango%2Cn%3A!1000%2Cn%3A5&bbn=1000&keywords=django&ie=UTF8&qid=1294137995&rnid=1000) just to learn web development basics and gain confidence before jumping into pyramid again.